# how to call a command with redirection from python

Tags: terminal, mount, python

I can mount (in the fxce4-terminal) successfully with something like:

```
sshfs -o password_stdin user@example.ddnss.de:/remote/path ~/example_local_path/ <<< 'password'
```

but not (in a python3-Terminal or an python3-script):

```
import os
os.system("sshfs -o password_stdin user@example.ddnss.de:/remote/path ~/example_local_path/ <<< 'password'")
```

the latter return an `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Why fails the command when called from python, while it works from the terminal? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The here-string syntax you tried to use is Bash-specific; `os.system()` runs `sh`.

You're better off using `subprocess` anyway, as also recommended by the `os.system()` documentation.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(
    ["sshfs", "-o", "password_stdin",
      "user@example.ddnss.de:/remote/path", 
      "~/example_local_path/"],
    input='password', text=True)
```

Splitting the command into a list of tokens removes the need for `shell=True` which you generally want to avoid, *especially* if you aren't very familiar with the shell. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)